# Connection to server with android using php

Tags: android

This is the code:

```
public boolean add(){

    HttpClient cliente;
    List<NameValuePair> lista;
    HttpPost post;
    cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
    post = new HttpPost("http://pruebamysqlandroid.esy.es/conexion/conexion.php");
    lista = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    lista.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", contactname.getText().toString()));
    lista.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numbretlf", tlf.getText().toString()));
    lista.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString()));
    try{
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(lista));
        cliente.execute(post);//here is the error
        return true;
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

When i try to add the contact to the server an error dont let me did 
help me please

The error is :

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Try make this in AsynTask. That what you tells the error.
And this is [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/2685996)

Comment: Try  this  volley libraray it maintains the queues of you request and handles other matters very effeiciantly http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You connect to network in UI thread (Main thread). For example use AsyncTask to connect in other thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do any network in Main thread，this will cause ANR. See [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or  [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your code in a separate Thread. e.g. Thread, HandlerThread or AsyncTask.